# Change bootstrap sass breaking points

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to stack two columns when the size of the screen is between 768 and 1024 pixels.
How can I achieve that ? Do I have to change any bootstrap variable ?
I use bootstrap-sass.

Answer (score 0):

The default breakpoint in Bootstrap are:

- Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

(source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

When you are using SASS you can override the following variables:

```
// Extra small screen / phone
//** Deprecated `$screen-xs` as of v3.0.1
$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

// Small screen / tablet
//** Deprecated `$screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-md` as of v3.0.1
$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg:                  1200px !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;

// So media queries don't overlap when required, provide a maximum
$screen-xs-max:              ($screen-sm-min - 1) !default;
$screen-sm-max:              ($screen-md-min - 1) !default;
$screen-md-max:              ($screen-lg-min - 1) !default;
```

So you need to choose which breakpoint you will change. I would say you only set (in your own variables.scss! NEVER adjust the bootstrap _variables.scss itself.) the $screen-md to 1024px. After you have done this you can use the bootstrap col classes to determine when to stack and when not.

```
<div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-12  col-md-12  col-lg-6">...</div>
```

This will stack on SM and MD size. On LG and XS it will take 50% of the available width.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have changed $screen-md to 1025px, it's partially working,
I use col-md-8 and it stacks for smaller screens, the only problem is that it stacks on screens <= 1023px and not for <= 1024px.

Comment: When you only set the screen-md to 1025px and setup your class to "col-xs-6  col-sm-6  col-md-8  col-lg-6" it means that if your screen size is between exact 1025px up to exact 1199px it will stack, below or above that they will align besides each-other. Can you post your class or maybe setup a small fiddle? This fiddle shows what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9966/ But with the regular sizes. You need to stretch the output window to see the changes.